# What chakra nature does the Nine-Tailed Fox have?

Tags: naruto

I want to know the chakra nature(s) of the Nine-Tailed Fox,
Kurama. Not the chakra nature of Naruto, I already know that. This is all I need to know.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Narutopedia](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kurama), the anime version specifies both fire and wind natures.

The reality is that the Bijuu are just a ***huge*** mass of chakra, and specific elemental natures don't really matter when you're dealing with chakra at that magnitude.